# Removing label date from bibitems (apa style) in Curve CV Overleaf template completely impossible

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biber, apa-style, overleaf

I'm trying to edit this overleaf template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-customised-curve-cv/mvmbhkwsnmwv

In particular I want to completely remove the label date from the bibliography items, since it does not suit my field.

Surname N. (2019). A nice paper.  -->> Surname N.. A nice paper.

I concentrated most of my effort in the setting.sty file, where alle the packages are loaded.

Disclaimer: I **need** to stick with the apa style otherwise the whole bibliography template breaks down.

I tried every solution I found (~2 hours of failures) before coming here as a last resort.

I tried to add at the already existing

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{extrayear}\clearfield{extradate}\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}
```

Without success, as any of the countless formatting solutions.

It seems that none of the field manipulation options works in this template ad I do not know why.

Can someone help me?

Thanks, Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the year from the bibliography by redefining the relevant macro.

For the outdated version of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` on Overleaf you will need

```
\renewbibmacro*{labelyear+extrayear}{}
```

For more recent versions

```
\renewbibmacro*{labelyear+extradate}{}
```

should be the right command.